# Need help with javascript reg ex - how to remove part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove everything after the last '/'.

Source: `/uploads/images/image1.jpg`
Result: `/uploads/images/`

How do I do this with regular expression?
I've tried different solutions, but it's not working. I get NULL as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No regex needed:

```
path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Reference: [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf), [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

You might want to check beforehand, whether the string contains a slash:

```
var index = path.lastIndexOf('/');
if(index > -1) {
    path = path.substring(0, index + 1);
}
```

Comment: The string will always contain a slash, because tha's what I have coded in the plugin. But never the less, a nice controll:)

Comment: Felix - Technically you'll want to add `1` to `path.lastIndexOf('/')` in order to get the result requested in the question. :o)